# Docker Nodejs Image Config

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I am new to Docker, I have a React.js app with the build forder (`npm run build`), I want to dockerize my app to make a container.

I made a Dockerfile with this config:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I got those images : [dockerimages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAEj9.png).

Can I dockerize only the build path which is 20MB or the image size is normal?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using multistage **Dockerfile**, I'm using this for **VueJS** and **Angular**.

**Bonus:** you can use NGINX for proxying your requests to your app.

NGINX config and **.dockerignore** files can be found [here](https://github.com/waqasdilawar/vue-for-docker).

```
##### 01- Build app
FROM node:lts-alpine as node
LABEL author="Waqas Dilawar"
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

##### 02- Run NGINX using build from step 01
FROM nginx:alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: +1. Minor comment: couldn't you move the `COPY . .` command up and remove the `COPY package.json ./` command?

Comment: @MattBrowne I've added node_modules in .dockerignore.  COPY package.json ./  command along lock file speeds up the installation if we have already.Thanks for npm install --production, I'll update answer.

Comment: Nice... but regarding `install --production`, I edited my comment when I realized this example is for a single-page app with no node server, and you're only copying the `dist` folder to the run-time image. And in many cases, `npm run build` depends on dev dependencies. In the case where you do have a node server, I was suggesting doing `npm install --production` in the nginx (run-time) image, not the build image.

Comment: thank you , and please how can I run my docker image into nginx ?

Comment: Just copy config folder from GitHub repository to your root folder and after building the image run the container NGINX will be up and running at port 80.