# Azure App Service Multi-container (preview) NGINX connect() failed (111: Connection refused) issue

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, docker-compose, azure-appservice

My `nginx.conf` works as expected locally without error, but when moving to this App Service environment I get the errors outlined below.

I am developing a React app built on TypeScript using the [Azure App Service multi-container (preview) app in Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app), but running into some issues with NGINX. The main errors I get are some error logs saying this when I try to run the App Service:

- *"connect() failed (111: Connection refused)"*
- *"no live upstreams while connecting to upstream"*

My `WEBSITES_PORT` under `App Service > Settings > Configuration` is set to `80`. I have also tried to set it to `80:80`. In both cases I get the same error logs below. Setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to `3001` and removing nginx from the list of services in the container settings file results in the App Service deploying successfully.

Let me know if there are other files I can provide in addition to the ones below.

My container settings found under `App Service > Settings > Container Settings` pointing to my private Azure Container Registry that stores all of my application images. The structure is very similar to the docker compose file I use for local deployment.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
 mysite:
  image: "reactapp.azurecr.io/my_site_img"
  ports:
  - "3001:3001"
 nginx:
  image: "reactapp.azurecr.io/nginx"
  ports:
  - "80:80"
```

An `nginx.conf` that controls the routing in my nginx image.

```
upstream my_site_proxy {
  server localhost:3001;
}
server {
  listen       0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name  localhost;
  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://my_site_proxy/;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

The Error Log file that is generated when I try to run my Azure App Service with the above configuration.

```sh
2020-07-13T01:22:52.929149550Z 2020/07/13 01:22:52 [error] 27#27: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots1234.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/robots1234.txt", host: "127.0.0.1:4548"
2020-07-13T01:22:52.929653182Z 2020/07/13 01:22:52 [warn] 27#27: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots1234.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/robots1234.txt", host: "127.0.0.1:4548"
2020-07-13T01:22:52.930048306Z 2020/07/13 01:22:52 [error] 27#27: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots1234.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/robots1234.txt", host: "127.0.0.1:4548"
2020-07-13T01:22:52.930060507Z 2020/07/13 01:22:52 [warn] 27#27: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots1234.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/robots1234.txt", host: "127.0.0.1:4548"
2020-07-13T01:22:52.936363702Z 172.16.7.1 - - [13/Jul/2020:01:22:52 +0000] "GET /robots1234.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "-" "-"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.004840493Z 2020/07/13 01:22:53 [error] 27#27: *1 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://my_site_proxy /robots933456.txt", host: "127.0.0.1:4548"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.005790052Z 172.16.7.1 - - [13/Jul/2020:01:22:53 +0000] "GET /robots933456.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "-" "-"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.024544427Z 2020/07/13 01:22:53 [error] 27#27: *4 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://my_site_proxy /", host: "mysite.azurewebsites.net", referrer: "https://portal.azure.com/"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.025501687Z 172.16.7.1 - - [13/Jul/2020:01:22:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "https://portal.azure.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "198.8.81.196:62138"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.152345935Z 2020/07/13 01:22:53 [error] 27#27: *5 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 172.16.7.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://my_site_proxy /favicon.ico", host: "mysite.azurewebsites.net", referrer: "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/"
2020-07-13T01:22:53.153395901Z 172.16.7.1 - - [13/Jul/2020:01:22:53 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36" "198.8.81.196:62138"
```

Comment: Can you just use **multistage** approach for building and running docker container instead of two containers as mentioned [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example). If yes then I've successfully deployed SPA in Azure and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62913449/6332074) can help you further in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your nginx upstream configuration to this:

```
upstream my_site_proxy {
  server mysite:3001;
}
```

You should connect to `mysite`, which is the name of your app container. Docker will resolve this DNS name to the IP address of the app container. You would only connect to `localhost` if you were running nginx and your app inside the same container (which is not best practice.)

Comment: I will try this, you choose to use `server mysite:3001;` because `mysite` is what I named my website service in my container settings .yml file? just pushed my changed and will let you know how the build goes.

Comment: Right. I'm looking at your docker-compose.yml file.

Comment: Still have the same issue do I need to change the `server_name` in the `server` block as well? From `server_name  localhost` to `server_name  nginx`?

Comment: The `server_name` should be set to what the hostname is from the client's perspective. So if you type in `http://mysite.biz` to get to your site, then the `server_name` should be `mysite.biz`. Alternatively you can use a `server_name` of `_` to match all hostnames. [Documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Comment: Right now I expect the user to type in `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net` to get to my site, so I should use this as the server name? I will also try `_`.