# Docker compose error: nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:21

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Trying to run nginx and web application via docker compose

dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.2 as build

RUN mkdir /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . /app
RUN npm run-script build

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/roundmap.app

EXPOSE 3000
```

nginx config defauls.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 3000;
  server_name *.roundmap.app 185.146.157.206;

  root /var/www/roundmap.app;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://app:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "4"
services:
    app:
        build: roundmap/
        container_name: app
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17.2-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        links:
            - app
        volumes:
            - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.crt:/etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.crt
            - /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.key:/etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.key
```

running via docker-compose up
and getting error

nginx    | 2020/07/20 16:39:19 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:22
nginx    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:22
nginx exited with code 1

Сan you please help where am I mistaken?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62913449/6332074) might help.

Comment: Thank you, but I am goind add another container for rest api, it will use also 443 port and it is impossible to run miltiple containers on the same port, so need proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `default.conf` replace `https://app:3000` by `http://app:3000` as SSL termination is happening at Nginx itself, app is still using http.

Update your `docker-compose.yaml`

Use `depends_on` instead of `links`, it has deprecated.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
        build: roundmap/
        container_name: app
        command: [ "node", "app.js"]
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17.2-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on:
            - app
        volumes:
            - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.crt:/etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.crt
            - /etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.key:/etc/ssl/roundmap/roundmap.key
```

Comment: ur also missing `command` in docker-compose to start ur nodejs app like: `command: node server.js`